Machine Learning Model on Tensorflow, CUDA, cuDNN not working
I am trying to run ResNet152 on Jupyter Notebooks within a Conda Environment. Here's my code:
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50, ResNet101, ResNet152, InceptionResNetV2, DenseNet121
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Activation, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras import mixed_precision, layers, models
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers.schedules import ExponentialDecay
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, RMSprop

mixed_precision.set_global_policy('mixed_float16')

base_model = ResNet152(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(256, 256, 3))


for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = True 

pooling_layer = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(base_model.output)  # GlobalAveragePooling2D layer
output_layer = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='output_layer')(pooling_layer)

model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output_layer)

initial_learning_rate = 0.001
lr_schedule = ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate,
    decay_steps=50,  # Adjust the decay steps as needed
    decay_rate=0.9,     # Adjust the decay rate as needed
    staircase=False)

optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule)

model.compile(
    optimizer=optimizer,
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.Precision(), tf.keras.metrics.Recall(), tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc')]
)

model.summary()

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0'
history = model.fit(dataset_batched_withoutnames, epochs=5)

I get the following error:
DNN library is not found.
     [[{{node model/conv1_conv/Conv2D}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_55822]

(there's a long box but didn't copy and paste it all)
I went back and downgraded my Tensorflow, CUDA, and cuDNN. I am on CUDA 11.2, cuDNN 8.1.0 and Tensorflow 2.10.0
I went back to my paths and have cleaned it all up and I added all the following to path

Why this isn't working?

I'd recommend you install cuda via pip if you can (https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#pip-wheels).

Thanks! I ended up doing a completely fresh environment and installed it as you suggested. This resolved the issues. Thanks!!!!

DNN library is not found. generally means that CUDA is not properly installed or the the wrong CUDA dependencies are installed. As a first step you can check the installation is working by running nvidia-smi in the terminal.

I ran it and it shows CUDA 12.5. I did explicitly downgrade to CUDA 11.2.. When I run NVCC--version it shows Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Nov_30_19:15:10_Pacific_Standard_Time_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.2, V11.2.67
Build cuda_11.2.r11.2/compiler.29373293_0 .... is there a reason my nvidia-smi shows this?

nvidia-smi just shows the maximum supported cuda version for the graphics driver you have installed - it's not showing what's actually (or even) installed. All nvidia-smi tells you is that you've installed a cuda compatible driver correctly.
